# i want to install specific version of go programming language(1.7.5 ) in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, bash, golang

```
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.7.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz
```

extract the package

```
sudo tar -zxvf go1.7.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
```

Added by Go Path

```
echo 'export GOROOT=/usr/local/go' >> ~/.bashrc

echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go' >> ~/.bashrc 

echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

i am getting error when typing

```
go version
```

-bash: /usr/bin/go: No such file or directory

Comment: Did you resource your .bashrc after your changes --> `source .bashrc` or restart the terminal window.

Answer (score 0):

I just make a symlink from /usr/bin/go to the particular go binary file I want, that way the OS can always find it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mention how to create the symlink